# Null pointer when referencing canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to paint on top of a canvas, but every time I try, I get an error saying that something is null. I am very confused why this is occurring, because when I test my code in a web browser, my canvas is drawn onto the screen. Does anyone have any ideas why I keep getting a null exception in my code?

JavaScript function:

```
function draw() {
var tw = canvas.width/grid.width;
var th = canvas.height/grid.height;

for (var x = 0; x < grid.width; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < grid.height; y++) {
    switch (grid.get(x, y)) {
      case EMPTY:
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ccc";
        break;
      case PLAYER1:
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        break;
      case PLAYER2:
        ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
        break;
    }
    ctx.fillRect(x * tw, y * th, tw, th);
  }
}
```

where I am getting my null exception:

```
var canvas, ctx, keystate1, frames, score = {p1: 0, p2: 0};

function main() {
   canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

My exception is occurring at when I am trying to define ctx

```
</div>
</center>

<center>
<div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
</center>

</form>
  <div style="text-align:center;width:480px;">
  <button onclick="ifi()">Start</button>
</div>
```

Html canvas initialization:

```
</div>
</center>

<center>
<div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
</center>

</form>
<div style="text-align:center;width:480px;">
<button onclick="ifi()">Start</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, if you want people to help they'll need to be able to reproduce your problem. Please post minimal, complete, verifiable code (not as images): https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: For some reason you are not getting anything from `getElementById()`. Are you running code before the DOM is ready? Have you double checked the `Id`? There's not much else people can help with unless you post code the reproduces the problem.

Comment: Not enough code to determine an answer. We can't see your `grid`. Also, every one of your `case`s within that `switch` is a `var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script source tag is in the head of your html file, try moving it to the line just below the canvas in the body. If this is the case your JS is running before the element is created. Since you have an inline width and height the canvas is still being drawn in the browser, but by then its too late.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="yourCanvas"></canvas>
    <script src="yourScript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```